# Pandas equivalent of R/dplyr group_by summarise concatenation

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr

I have an operation I need to translate from `dplyr` (and `stringr`) in R to `pandas` in python. It's quite simple in R but I haven't been able to wrap my head around it in pandas. Basically, I need to group by one (or more) columns, and then concatenate the remaining columns together and collapse them by a delimiter. R has the nicely vectorized `str_c` function that does exactly what I want.

Here's the R code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- as_tibble(structure(list(file = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), marker = c("coi", "12s", "16s", "coi", "12s", "16s"), start = c(1, 22, 99, 12, 212, 199), end = c(15, 35, 102, 150, 350, 1102)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame") )

df %>%
  group_by(file) %>%
  summarise(markers = str_c(marker,"[",start,":",end,"]",collapse="|"))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>    file markers                               
#>   <dbl> <chr>                                 
#> 1     1 coi[1:15]|12s[22:35]|16s[99:102]      
#> 2     2 coi[12:150]|12s[212:350]|16s[199:1102]
```

Here's the beginning of the python code. I assume there's some trickery with `agg` or `transform` but I'm not sure how to combine and join the multiple columns:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = StringIO("""
file,marker,start,end
1.f,coi,1,15
1.f,12s,22,35
1.f,16s,99,102
2.f,coi,12,150
2.f,12s,212,350
2.f,16s,199,1102
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s)

# ... now what? ...
```

Comment: You could also check siuba, or dplython

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
(df.astype(str)
   .assign(markers = lambda df: df.marker + "[" + (df.start + ":"+df.end) + "]")
   .groupby('file', as_index=False)
   .markers
   .agg("|".join)
)
 
  file                                 markers
0  1.f        coi[1:15]|12s[22:35]|16s[99:102]
1  2.f  coi[12:150]|12s[212:350]|16s[199:1102]
```

The idea is to combine the columns first before grouping and aggregatiing with python's str.join method

Comment: you need the lambda since there is a data type change at the start (`astype`). of course, if the df was a string, I wouldnt bother with the change

Comment: I had to remove the `as_index=False` part to get this to work. Otherwise, it does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Create new column markers which concatenates marker and the last two columns separated by:

Groupby by file and concatenate the new column markers.

```
df['markers']=df['marker']+'['+(df.astype(str).iloc[:,2:].agg(list,1).str.join(':'))+']'
df.groupby('file')['markers'].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep='|')).to_frame()

                                 markers
file                                        
1.f         coi[1:15]|12s[22:35]|16s[99:102]
2.f   coi[12:150]|12s[212:350]|16s[199:1102]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) similarly as you do in R:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, group_by, summarise, paste0
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     file=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
...     marker=["coi", "12s", "16s"] * 2,
...     start=[1, 22, 99, 12, 212, 199],
...     end=[15, 35, 102, 1150, 350, 1102],
... )
>>> (
...     df
...     >> group_by(f.file)
...     >> summarise(
...         markers=paste0(
...             f.marker, "[", f.start, ":", f.end, "]",
...             collapse="|",
...         )
...     )
... )
     file                                  markers
  <int64>                                 <object>
0       1         coi[1:15]|12s[22:35]|16s[99:102]
1       2  coi[12:1150]|12s[212:350]|16s[199:1102]
```